# Remove empty headings that contain additional empty html tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script in my code to remove all empty heading tags so they're not read by screen readers:

```
    $("h1:empty, h2:empty, h3:empty, h4:empty, h5:empty, h6:empty").replaceWith('');
```

but it's not picking up heading tags that contain additional empty html like `<h2><strong></strong></h2>`

How can I also remove these?

Comment: Why JavaScript? If the page is static then just remove those empty headings. If it is dynamically generated then fix the source of those empty headings.

Comment: It's from a CMS and unfortunately it's too time consuming to remove all the ones that have been added accidentally.

Comment: Don't use JS as a crutch for fixing UI problems. It may be quicker in dev time, but if the page loads slowly then those elements will still be visible until the DOM loads.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `text()` property.

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function(){
    if( $(this).text().trim() === '' )
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do this with vanilla JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').forEach(el =>
  !el.textContent.replace(/(\s|\n)+/g, '') && el.remove());
```

```html
<h1>abc</h1>
<h2>def</h2>
<h3>
  <strong>
  
  </strong>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in JavaScript

```js
const tags = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'];
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(tags.join(','));
nodes.forEach(elm => {
   if (elm.innerText.trim() === "") {
      elm.remove();
   }
});
console.log(document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="result">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2><strong>   </strong></h2>
<h3>Element</h3>
<h4> </h4>
<h2>
  <p>
    <strong>   </strong>
  </p>
  <span> </span>
</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I missed the `nodeList.forEach` change somehow. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:only-child` pseudo class to select elements which are the only child of a parent element, remove the node, then check if the parent node has `.children`, if not remove the parent node

```
let nodes = document.querySelector("div")
            .querySelectorAll(":only-child");

nodes.forEach(node => {
  if (!node.childNodes.length) {
    let parent = node.parentNode;
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    if (!parent.children.length) {
      parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent)
    }
  }
});

console.log(document.querySelector("div").innerHTML);
```

I tested it on the following code

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `.querySelector().querySelectorAll()`? And why only the first `<div>`?

Comment: This is just an example of what he asked for,
And the div, this means the main div in its code.

Answer (score 0):

This script would be helpful:

```js
function onlyHaveEmpty(el){
  el = $(el);
  result = true;
  if(el.is(':empty')){
    return true;
  }else{
    if(el.children().length==0){
      return false;
    }else{
      el.children().each(function(idx, child){
        if(!onlyHaveEmpty(child)){
          result = false;
          return;
        }
      });
      return result;
    }
  }
}

$(":header").each(function(idx, el){
  if(onlyHaveEmpty(el)){
    el.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello!</p>
<h1></h1>
<h3>It's me.</h3>
<p>World!</p>
<h2><strong></strong></h2>
<h2><strong>Hi!</strong></h2>
```